# Grouping all files from one directory under one alias

Tags: typescript, path, alias, tsconfig

Let's say I have this directory structure:

```
src
├──Utils
|  ├──File2.ts
|  ├──File3.ts
index.ts
tsconfig.json
```

I know you can set path aliases inside tsconfig.json like so:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        .....
        "paths": {
            "Utils/*": ["src/Utils/*"],
        }
    }
}
```

And then I can use these aliases inside my index.ts:

```
import { File2 } from 'Utils/File2';
import { File3 } from 'Utils/File3';
```

I am sure you noticed the redundancy: even so if the `File2` and `File3` are in the same folder we have to write the `import` for each file inside `Utils` folder.

Is it possible to groups these files under one import and use it like in the example below?

```
import { File2, File3 } from 'Utils';
```

I tried this configuration but it doesn't work:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "Utils": ["src/Utils/*"],
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, I would like NOT to use a barrel file like `index.ts` where I export everything from the `Utils` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is solvable by using a barrel file. Create an `index.ts` file in `/Utils` and add

```
export * from './File2';
export * from './File2';
```

and in your `tsconfig`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "Utils": ["src/Utils"]
        }
    }
}
```

It is not possible group these imports without using a barrel file. However, there are libraries that can generate these files for you if you don't want the hassle of manually maintaining them like [barrelsby](https://www.npmjs.com/package/barrelsby). Alternatively, you could write your own script to keep them up to date.

Comment: aaah. I forgot to mention this. I would like without that barrel file :(. This is because the Utils folder will have a lot of files inside and I don't want to update index.ts every time I add a new file.

Comment: That's not possible then AFAIK. Typescript needs a file to import from. I'd suggest writing a small script that generates and updates the barrel file during your build step as a workaround.

Comment: Would typescript transformers do it?

Comment: I never experimented with transformers but they should be able to solve this. I'd recommend using a library for that though (updated my answer on that).